# Algorithm to remove unnecessary productions from context-free grammar

Tags: fl.formal-languages, context-free, grammars, minimization

I have a context free grammar and I want to remove productions that will lead to infinite derivations because they are "cyclic". An example would be:

```
S -> a | aA | EF
A -> aB | aC
B -> aA
C -> DBF
D -> A
E -> S
F -> a
```

Here productions including A, B, C and D could be removed without affecting the produced language (I think?), because there are cycles that will never lead to a word: A -> B -> A, A -> C -> D -> A

Now I am looking for an algorithm that can remove these "unnecessary" productions.
My problem is that most of the posts or suggested algorithms that deal with cycles only refer to unit rules. I'm not sure if I've misunderstood something here and the algorithm I am looking for could work similarly to removing cycles by removing unit rules, but I don't think so.

My first idea was to list all nonterminals that don't directly produce words. Then, I would remove all nonterminals from this list that have at least one production that contains only nonterminals besides terminals that are not on the list. I would repeat this until the list no longer changes. The last step would be to remove all productions that contain nonterminals that are still on the list.
This method works well for my example, but I'm not sure if I've overlooked problems that might occur with other grammars.  I just want to get a smaller grammar so that there is no problem if I keep some unnecessary productions, but the resulting grammar should of course produce the same language as before.

Are there any methods/algorithms to solve my problem (and are there problems with my idea?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Reachability,_productiveness,_nullability

Comment: Oh. Well, I was probably right in assuming that I had overlooked something, I read this article before... Thank you very much!